# from an EnumerableRowCollection(Of System.Data.DataRow), assign the table to a variable

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, system.data

I have a method that is passed in an EnumerableRowCollection(Of System.Data.DataRow),i want to be able to use the underlying datatable. Ultimately i want to be able to use the columns collection of that datatable.

currently i use

```
Dim t As System.Data.DataTable = TryCast(x(0), DataRow).Table
```

where `x is EnumerableRowCollection(Of System.Data.DataRow`)

This works fine, EXCEPT for the case where the count of rows is zero.

I am convinced that the underlying datatable definition is still there as i am able to access it through the debugger if i 'add watch' against x

in the watch window i see

```
x|{System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection(of System.Data.DataRow)}
System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection(of System.Data.DataRow)|{System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection(of System.Data.DataRow)}
ElementType| {Name="DataRow" FullName = "System.Data.DataRow"}
EnumerableRows|In-Memory Query
Table|{mydatatable}
```

It is mydatatable that i am after

if i try 
    `x.Table`
then i get

> 'table' is not a member of 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of
>   System.Data.DataRow)'.

in my case the enumerablerowcollection is most likely being created from a datatable using LINQ with an orderby

```
 Dim z = (From d In mydataset.mydatatable.OrderBy(Function(c) c.myfield))
```

In summary, i want to be able to access the datatable  from an EnumerableRowCollection(Of System.Data.DataRow) even if the count of EnumerableRows is zero.
If this is not possible then please could you help me explain how teh watch window can display this. Am i allowed to add an image of what i am seeing in the watch window?
I have added the image of what the debugger shows, how does it get this table info
[image]

Comment: I don't have enough code here to test ideas, but what about just "faking it" by calling AddRow on the empty collection and reflecting that new row for your columns?

Comment: i will edit this tomorrow with a more useful code sample. i am having a little explore along the lines of your idea, i will update if that gets me anywhere

Comment: No, you cannot get info on the table from a zero-size collection. You would have to pass the table through another parameter.

Comment: Why do you want the underlying `DataTable`?  Can you not take in a `DataTable` instead of the row collection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not a public property or method that exposes the underlying `DataTable`.  The `Table` property you see in an `internal` property that is not publicly accessible.  You *could* dig into this implementation detail using reflection:

```
var pi = rows.GetType().GetProperty("Table",BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
DataTable dt = pi.GetValue(rows) as DataTable;
```

But (hopefully obviously) these internal implementation details are brittle and subject to change.

Since the class itself [is not intended to be used directly from your class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb907979(v=vs.110).aspx), I would strongly suggest changing your approach to take in a `DataTable` as a parameter instead of this implementation-specific class.

Comment: thanks, i have changed it to pass in the datatable as a parameter. I hadn't realized that EnumerableRowCollection was off-limits. I will use it for the short-term whilst i look for a better solution

Comment: @thehill  Yes it's unfortunate that the return type for the `AsEnumerable` extension method returns a specific class instead of an `IEnumerable<TDataRow>`.  That way they could change the actual implementation type without breaking existing code.